# Confused with the 2 different ideas on derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration

The professor explained two different things about derivatives:

1. It is related to a line connecting 2 points on a function
2. It can be calculated using rules

I can understand visually the first of those claims. Even when it requires infinitesimals. But the second one, the formulas, were derived algebraically.

Is there any way to build an intuition, or use another method other than infinitesimals to find out what a derivative of a function is, or this concept and results only arises when we use infinitesimals?

Any article for reading is welcome as long as it's not too technical.

Comment: I would recommend watching 3Blue1Brown videos.

Comment: The corresponding visualization can be given by secant and tangent lines. The derivative value of a function in a particular point is the slope of the tangent of this function in this point.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUvTyaaNkzM&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr

Comment: yea but i refer to the formulas @DimaMcGreen

Comment: @Forester I see. that's cool. But not all formulas can be derived geometrically, can they?

Comment: @Minsky You wanted to build an intuition right? His videos are very good if you want to build an intuition as you have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Forester yes but I dont believe in the formulas using limits ( or just can't process them ) and suppose there should be another way to get them.

Comment: @Minsky If you want to understand calculus you have to like and understand limits. I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: My constructive advice: study freshman kinematics. Look at simple paths of motion. Understand how velocity relates to position, understand how acceleration relates to both. In this sense, you can visualize everything without thinking about mathematical epsilons and so on. Nice and tangible.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamBarnes, true sometimes physics gives you good models.

Comment: There is (or should be) freedom of belief, but mathematics isn't about belief. It's about logic, definitions, rules. If you do a lot of those, you *may* develop some intuition. If you just talk about intuition *instead of* doing mathematics (learning definitions and rules, doing exercises instead of watching them done by others), you'll never acquire one bit of it.

Comment: really @ProfessorVector

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why do you think that these are "different things"? This is what is normal in mathematics: You define some concept, and then you use that definition to figure out various theorems and formulas related to that concept.

A right triangle is defined as three line segments sharing end points, with two of the segments being perpendicular to each other (which itself is defined as "if you extend one of the segments, the two angles formed by the other segment and the two sides of the extended segment are congruent"). There is no mention in the definition of any relationship between the lengths of the three sides. Yet still we are able to prove $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

The problem with derivatives is that the *idea* behind the derivative is not something we can *directly* calculate. But it is something we can approximate as closely as we like. And we leverage that ability to approximate it into indirect tools that we can calculate.

Calculus is the mathematics of refining approximations. And though it is generally held to have been invented by Leibniz and Newton, its roots are far older. They date back more than 2400 years to the [Method of Exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion) of Antiphon and Eudoxus. Though the method of exhaustion was originally developed as a tool for area calculation, the basic idea is more general:

If you have a quantity $M$ that you can only approximate, and you want to show it is equal to some number $m$, do this: For every $a < m$, approximate $M$ closely enough to show that it must be $> a$. For every $b > m$, approximate $M$ closely enough to show it must be $< b$. Now you've shown that $M$ is greater than every number less than $m$ and $M$ is less than every number greater than $m$. The only possibility left is that $M = m$.

A concrete example: Find the slope of the tangent line to $y =x^2$ at $x = 1$. The point of tangency is $(1,1)$. if I choose $x = z \ne 1$, I get a second point $(z, z^2)$ and can form the secant line passing through the two points. That line has slope:
$$m = \dfrac{z^2-1}{z-1} = \dfrac{(z+1)(z-1)}{z-1} = z + 1$$
I cannot have $z = 1$ in this equation because the fraction is not defined there. I can only say that $m = z+1$ when $z \ne 1$. If I were allowed to have $z = 1$, $2$ would be the obvious choice for the corresponding $m$. So how to show that $m$ actually is $2$ at $z = 1$? The idea is that the *derivative* is the value that the slopes approximate when $z$ is close to $1$, with the approximation improving as $z$ gets closer to $1$.

Suppose $a < 2$. I can choose a value for $z$ with $a - 1 < z < 1$, for example, the average $z = \frac {(a-1) + 1}2 = \frac a2$. Then $$m(z) = z + 1 > (a-1) + 1 = a$$
In particular, for any $z$ closer to $1$ than $a-1$, $m(z)$ is closer to $2$ than $a$. Thus the desired value of $m(1)$ cannot be $a$. The same is true when $a > 2$. Picking $1 < z < a-1$ gives $2 < m(z) < a$, so $m(1)$ cannot be $a$ either. Therefore the derivative $m(1)$ at $z = 1$ cannot be less than $2$ or greater than $2$. It must be $2$.

Notice that there is no mention of limits here. I've dodged around the language a bit to avoid getting into certain issues that would dramatically lengthen this post, but the whole concept of the derivative can be defined without actually discussing the idea of a limit. This is somewhat of a cheat, because the idea *behind* the limit is still there. But discussions of infinitesimals or of epsilons and deltas are not. You just eliminate all values but one from being a possibility, and define the derivative to be the one that is left. "Limits" themselves are just a way of cleaning up the process.

Notice also that even though I started woking with just a vague idea of approximating the tangent slope with secant slopes, and produced my answer only from that idea, I found a nice formula in the middle that gave me the answer. The rest of the argument was devoted to showing that yes, it really was the answer. This is why the derivative is defined in terms of limits of secant lines, but then we have all these formulas for calculating it. The formulas follow from the definition.